# How to get text matching percentage in vespa?

Tags: vespa

Is there any functionality where we can search a text and we get the matching percentage that how much the test has been matched or string distance between searched text and result text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See textSimilarity(name).queryCoverage and textSimilarity(name).fieldCoverage for example.

This document lists all available ranking features in Vespa https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/rank-features.html